# How to test my newly developed mobile website Locally

Tags: mobile

So I have created a Mobile Website for personal purposes and to practice a little bit about Jquery mobile. I was just wondering if how can I test my Mobile Website Locally in my station, since I don't have a server yet or an FTP to get this Uploaded via internet.

Can someone suggest how can I do this? I see a lot of emulators but I think before I can test through that emulators is I have to upload my site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to modify browser headers:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-headers/

or this

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/

Comment: Thanks, This is a great addon.

Answer (score 1):

You can download a server application locally - no need to upload. Depending in what you have developed the site in you will need different capabilities (eg PHP will require a PHP runtime).

For that matter, most operating systems ship with an http server: Windows and IIS, OSX and "web sharing" (Apache httpd), and most Linux distributions either bundle one or have one an installer readily available.

If those are not appealing or available, you can get one that can install locally or run from a USB drive: [Portable servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_portable_software#HTTP_servers)

To test with a local http server you will direct your browser at http://localhost/ where path depends on how you set up the server software.

Comment: This is a great help. Thank you.