# Testing mobile websites locally

Tags: web, mamp

I currently have a project in which I need to develop a web application for mobile devices. I've always tested my websites locally using MAMP on mac, but I have no idea how to do the same for a mobile device. I've found loads of websites that let you check a live website but seeing as all my code will be local they are no good. I've also found some applications that forward to a connected phone but all are on the Windows platform so no good once again. I'm looking for a solution in which I can just point my phone to a local url and view the site.

Comment: realted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475659/how-to-test-my-newly-developed-mobile-website-locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a REALLY simple way of doing it in the end. It was as simple as putting in my laptops IP address followed by :8888. It allows me to see the websites as I would straight on the machine!

Answer (score 0):

You need a box that acts as a DNS-Server.
In our Network we have a mac mini server which acts as a DNS-Server too.
We enter the new zone like:

```
mysite.dev 192.168.x.x (IP of you computer)
www.mysite.dev mysite.dev
```

Enter the ip of your server in your smartphone (WLAN should be same net) as DNS and that's it.
Then type http://mysite.dev on your phone.

Comment: I have an old server somewhere but haven't ran it in ages. Surely there's a simpler way than using a separate box? Only other alternative I have is to just use a web browser plugin to set window sizes, which isn't ideal.

Comment: this is imho the best way if you'll use it a lot and you have several devices. otherwise you could edit the host-file on your phone to point to you computer.

Comment: It's just for a university project so it will be used a lot, but only for a couple of months then no longer.

Comment: But then how do you get a certificate for a site in `.dev`, a made up TLD?

Comment: selfmade. openssl.